# Laravel DomainException in RouteCompiler Variable name cannot be longer than 32 characters in route pattern

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error because of a long variable name.
How do I override the variable name?

I would very much like to keep the resource name.

My route is:

```
Route::resource(
    'computer-software-version-installation',
    'Web\Model\ComputerSoftwareVersionInstallationController'
);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix:

```
    Route::resource(
        'computer-software-version-installation',
        'Web\Model\ComputerSoftwareVersionInstallationController',
        ['parameters' => [
            'computer-software-version-installation' => 'installation'
        ]]
    );
```

Why is this necessary?

For Laravel 5.3, here is the extended answer:

The [Illuminate\Routing\Router `resource` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L282) creates a new ResourceRegistrar to register the routes.  This method as an `$options` parameter.

The [Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar `register` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php#L91) will set the parameters attribute to the `$options['parameters']` value, then calls `getResourceWildcard` to set the `$base` variable value using the last part of the `$name` as the input parameter.

The [Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar `getResourceWildcard` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php#L261) will look through the parameters to see if there is a value, and use it if there is.  Otherwise it goes through some gyrations to make a string.

So if we pass in a `'parameters'` array with a key that matches the route name, and the value equal to the place-holder name, we can avoid the error.

The issue with `getResourceWildcard` was mentioned here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1001#issuecomment-134887584

but seemed to be rebutted here as a Symphony issue?

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1001#issuecomment-212518768

Hopefully, this answer helps someone else with a work around.  But it has not been extensively tested, so it may still have problems.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a relevant discussion. The issue seems to be more directly tied to Sympfony.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1001